# How to resolve this: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const uint8_t*

Tags: c++, arduino, sha, hmac, arduino-ide

I installed this SHA library: https://github.com/Cathedrow/Cryptosuite. I want to implement HMAC256 using Arduino IDE 1.6.7 installed on Win. 10 and the controller is ATMEGA328.

I copied the example given in their webpage. I am still new and want to test and try. I wrote this code in Arduino IDE.

```
#include "sha256.h"

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    uint8_t *hash;
    //static const char hash[450]={};
    //const char *hash; hash={};
    Sha256.initHmac("hash key",8); // key, and length of key in bytes
    Sha256.print("This is a message to hash");
    hash = Sha256.resultHmac();
    //Serial.print(hash,HEX);
}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

I got this error:

> invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const uint8_t* {aka const
>   unsigned char*}' [-fpermissive]

I do not know why this happens. The example is primitive taken as is from the library site. Can you help?

**EDIT:**
I tried to change the line from:

```
Sha256.initHmac((const uint8_t*)"hash key",8);
```

to:

```
Sha256.initHmac((const uint8_t*)"hash key",8);
```

But again, the compilation fails. It says:

> Arduino: 1.6.7 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"
>
> In file included from C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/arduino.h:28:0,
>
> ```
>              from C:\Users\e\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Sha\sha1_config.h:13,
>
>              from C:\Users\e\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Sha\sha1.h:4,
>
>              from C:\Users\e\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Sha\sha1.cpp:1:
> ```
>
> C:\Users\e\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Sha\sha1.cpp:8:25: error:
>   variable 'sha1InitState' must be const in order to be put into
>   read-only section by means of '**attribute**((progmem))'
>
> uint8_t sha1InitState[] PROGMEM = {
>
> ```
>                      ^
> ```
>
> exit status 1 Error compiling.
>
> This report would have more information with   "Show verbose output
>   during compilation"   enabled in File > Preferences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `initHmac` function signature is:

```
void initHmac(const uint8_t* secret, int secretLength);
```

But you use `const char*` for secret.

**Solution**

Try to cast the secret variable to `const uint8_t*` (or `const unsigned char*`):

```
Sha256.initHmac((const uint8_t*)"hash key",8);
```

**UPDATE**

To solve your new compilation error, just add `const` in front of all declarations containing `PROGMEM` in the library sources. For insance:

In *Sha/sha1.cpp (line 11)*

```
const uint8_t sha1InitState[] PROGMEM = {
```

In *Sha/sha256.cpp (line 6)*

```
const uint32_t sha256K[] PROGMEM = {
```

In *Sha/sha256.cpp (line 11)*:

```
const uint8_t sha256InitState[] PROGMEM = {
```

Comment: Thanks. But did not solve the problem. See the post edited.

Comment: See update (this is another issue which is not associated with your initial error)